# Compare Date to String Date Value Swift

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

I am trying to convert a string date into date type. But when I am trying this code given below return nil value after I compare the two dates with each other, one is selected date from date picker and the second is current date, but always give my return no.

I am really confused how to convert string date to date type  and after compare two dates with each other please check code below:

**Code**

```
    let currentDate = Date()
    let currentDformatter = DateFormatter()
    currentDformatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    let currentDateResult = currentDformatter.date(from: "\(currentDate)")
    print("Current Latest Date ",currentDateResult as Any)

    let selectedDate = Date()
    let selectedDformatter = DateFormatter()
    selectedDformatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    let selectedresult = selectedDformatter.string(from: selectedDate)
    print("Current Latest Date ",selectedresult)

    if currentDateResult == selectedDate{
        print("yes")
    }else{
        print("no")
    }
```

And i am also compare the time please give me advice on how can i prevent the user from selecting time in time picker beyond a certain time. For example like restaurant closing time is 5'o clock.

**Code:**

```
CurrentDateAndTime 2019-04-15 05:00:00 +0000

SelectDateAndTime  2019-04-16 07:52:28 +0000
```

I do not want the user to select time after 5'o clock , how can i check and compare the time??

how can i check and compare the time??

Comment: are you sure that the string you trying to convert is in this format "dd-MM-yyyy" ?

Comment: The selected date from the date picker is also a `Date`, not a string, so why don't you simply compare those two `Date` types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way to check if two dates are in the same day

```
let currentDate = Date()
let selectedDate = Date()
if Calendar.current.isDate(currentDate, inSameDayAs: selectedDate) {
    print("yes")
} else {
    print("no")
}
```

Comment: and i am also compare the time please give me advice on how can i prevent the user from selecting time in time picker beyond a certain time. For example like restaurant closing time is 5'o clock and i do not want the user to select time after 5'o clock , how can i check and compare  the time??

Comment: You could compare the hour component: `let hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date()) > 17`

Comment: Did you try the suggestion in my last comment? Or set the minimum and maximum date of the date picker.

Comment: 17 for pm and 5 for am. This checks if the selected date is after 5 o'clock.

Comment: @ShamDass Do you want to not allow users to select after 5pm every day?

Comment: Yeah, I understand your point, but this is static value only for demo, I check user selected time with restaurant closed time.

Comment: no according to restaurant closing time  @RajeshKumarR

Comment: Please ask a new question and add more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
let currentDate = Date()
let currentDformatter = DateFormatter()
currentDformatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
let currentDateResult = currentDformatter.date(from: "\(currentDate)")
print("Current Latest Date ",currentDateResult as Any)
```

In the above code you are not actually converting Date object to String type. Interpolating it to string will only print out the object and its properties. You have to convert your date object to String.

```
let myDateInString = "22-08-2018"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
let date = formatter.date(from: myDateInString) // Optional
let stringVal = formatter.string(from: date!)
debugPrint(stringVal)
```

If you want to compare two dates you can use:

```
switch date1.compare(date2) {
case .orderedSame: break // exact same
case .orderedAscending: break // date2 comes after date1 in calendar
case .orderedDescending: break // date2 comes before date1 in calendar
}
```

If you just want to check if two dates are for same day, use @vadian's answer

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `currentDateResult` is `nil` because you are not passing right `date String`  so you need to convert the `date` into a `string` then pass the `string` into this like below:

```
let currentDateResult = currentDformatter.date(from: currentDformatter.string(from: currentDate))
```

Otherwise, you can do the same as the above @vadian answer